# Kde rendering issues after wake

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, kde, fonts, kde5

I have recently decided to switch my desktop environment from GNOME to KDE plasma. I am loving the new look, but I have this problem that when I put my PC to sleep, then after waking it, some text doesn't render correctly.

In particular, the text on the lock screen, like time and date has some missing characters and the icons on the desktop are completely messed up.

[image: Screenshot of my desktop after wake]

Of course, restarting the system helps, but I would like to avoid that if possible. Alternatively, if there is no known solution to this problem, how do I manage my desktop icons, so I can just remove them.

I use Kubuntu version 18.04 and KDE plasma version 5.12.9

Comment: That sounds as a bug which should be reported to the KDE developers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this worked for me:

> Linux uses CPU frequency scaling to save power; when the machine is resumed, it should start increasing the CPU frequency to meet the demands of the system, but it doesn’t always do that. A reboot fixes the problem, but who has time for that? The good news is that it’s an easy fix with the `cpupower` utility.

Instructions on this page: https://www.perl.com/article/fixing-a-sluggish-linux-after-suspend-resume/